# Rickshaw - Incompatibility between HoverDetail and RangeSlider

Tags: javascript, charts, rickshaw

I have a rickshaw graph with multiple data series on it (line graph)

I decided to have the hover detail and also a range slider preview at the bottom of the graph - however when I hover over the lines the detail always "snaps" to one line only.  If I take the range slider preview away it the hover detail works fine.

Anyone know whats wrong? Thanks in advance.

Code snippet:

```
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
                    element: document.querySelector('#timeSeriesPlot_'+index),
                    series: chartData,
                    renderer: 'multi',
                    width: jQuery('.chartAndLegend').width()-100,
                    height: 500,
                    dotSize: 2
              });

var xAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time( { graph: graph } );

var yAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y( {
              graph: graph,
              orientation: 'left',
              element: document.querySelector('#y_axis_'+index)
          } );

var hoverDetail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail( { graph: graph } );

var slider = new Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider.Preview({
                    graph: graph,
                    element: document.querySelector('#slider_'+index)
                  });

var legend = new Rickshaw.Graph.Legend({
                    graph: graph,
                    element: document.querySelector('#legend_'+index)
               });

var toggle = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle({
                graph: graph,
                legend: legend
              });

graph.render();
```

Screenshot - my mouse is actually above the top green line
[image: screenshot_graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Multi graphs in Rickshaw have `stack:true` by default. This makes the hover detail locations offset from the actual graph lines. It also causes other problems, such as [not allowing multiple series with different numbers of points](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/issues/315#issuecomment-45370454). To fix, just set `stack:false` in your Graph constructor arguments, as in:

```
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
                    element: document.querySelector('#timeSeriesPlot_'+index),
                    series: chartData,
                    renderer: 'multi',
                    width: jQuery('.chartAndLegend').width()-100,
                    height: 500,
                    dotSize: 2,
                    stack: false
              });
```